# Step Detector is not working

Tags: android, sensors

I wanted my program to basically pause when it does not detect a step. 
For checking this, I have added a toast, when the phone is kept still, but the toast is not generated, instead a System overlay dialog appears on the screen.

> Below is my code

```
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);


  @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            StepDetector = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
            if(StepDetector != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sensor is avaliable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mSensorManager.registerListener(this, StepDetector,
                        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sensor is unavaliable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if(event.values[0] != 1.0){
                TimeRan.stop();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Workout is Paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Unable to track the reason, any help would be very valuable..

--Thanks!